# Textbox data to xml in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anybody tell me how to convert the data in text box to xml with fixed tags in asp.net c#?
My textbox data can be:

```
<h1>hai</h1>
<h2>fine</h2>
```

and I want to convert data in h1 tag to head tag in xml and soon

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();       
xdoc.LoadXml(txtBox.Text);
```

Comment: LoadXml() loads an XML file, not convert a piece of text into a field with it's own tag.